# RollBack project give an error: Root element is missing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

after finishing compiling my program with VS2022 (Windows From app .net framework) programmed with visual basic, I rolled back the entire project folder (right click, properties, restore previous versions).
After the system finishes restoring, I start my project and it gives me this error:
": error : The project file could not be loaded. Root element is missing".

all the files are present in the folder, reading around I think it is an xml file problem as can also be seen from the log:
"GruppoZacco\GruppoZacco.vbproj: Error on line 1. Expected '<' but found 'null character'."

How can I do? Have I lost everything or is there a remedy?

if I try to open only the .vbproj file it continues to give me the same error.
I expect to find the xml file and edit it in order to start the project

Comment: Create a new project somewhere else and add your existing files to it.

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually caused by a corrupted project configuration file.

It is possible that your project configuration file encountered an unexpected situation during the rollback process.

You can try creating a new project and then copying the contents of the old project to the new project.

Or choose to create a new project and compare the contents of the .vbproj files of the two projects to fix the wrong part.